# how to update dom on receiving POST request?

Tags: jquery, flask, real-time

I have a server that receives POST request from another server.

Everytime it receives data, I want to update the client's dom with the received data.

How can you do this with jQuery without constantly polling the end point?

I am using flask as a server end point.

Comment: from one server to another? so are you using curl or something? you'd still need the client to send a request. either comet or eventsource is what you want i think

Comment: http://www.angularjs.org/